# Find $\min \{ x+y: x+2y \ge 5, 4x+y\ge6\}$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Find $\min \{ x+y: x+2y \ge 5, 4x+y\ge6\}$ Could anyone tell me what is the answer? Is it zero?

I drew all the lines: $x+y=0$ which intersect the 2nd line at $(2,-2)$.

and with the first line at $(-5,5)$.

Comment: You should graph it up. My guess is that it's obvious from a picture.

Comment: @stuartstevenson, it is. Provided, of course, you understand the geometric interpretation of linear programming.

Comment: You can also note that $7(x+y)=3(x+2y)+(4x+y)\geq 3\cdot 5+6=21$.  Therefore, $x+y\geq 3$.  Show that the inequality can become an equality.

Comment: @BarryCipra And that you know what numbers are.

Comment: @stuartstevenson, ah, no, just just that it's obvious what you need to do to find them.

Comment: @miosaki: The answer is $$\{3,\{x\to 1,y\to 2\}\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints can be written (with $s:=x+y$)$$s\ge5-y,\\s\ge\frac{6+3y}4.$$

As one of the bounds is decreasing and the other growing, the optimum is achieved when they are equal,
$$y=2,\\s=3.$$

Answer (score 3):

[image: enter image description here: the graph]

I think this graph is sufficient.